# Excel 2013 keeps crashing

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel VBA macro keeps crashing Excel spreadsheet. It might be because I am asking Excel to send multiple SMS texts/emails or perhaps my `keyval` function.

---

```
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim Flds As Variant

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim e As Integer

Dim em As String
Dim st As String
Dim str As String
Dim em2 As String

Dim mon As Worksheet

Sub SingleButtonEvent()
    Set mon = Sheets("MON")

    st = ""
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row < 30 Then
        a = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
        If mon.Cells(a, "BB") = "" Then
            'MsgBox "No Number in Column BB. Message Will Not Send", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        Else
            em = mon.Cells(a, "BB").Value

            With Cells(a, "AV").Font
                .Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
                .Size = 12
            End With

            Call SendSMS
        End If
    Else
        For b = 1 To 29
            If Cells(b, "B") <> 0 Then
                a = b
                If mon.Cells(a, "BB") = "" Then
                Else
                    em = mon.Cells(a, "BB").Value
                    Call SendSMS
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub

Sub SendSMS()
    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    iConf.Fields.Update

    iMsg.To = em
    'Change Bellow email to your email
    iMsg.From = "test@gmail.com"
    iMsg.Subject = ""
    c = Cells(a, "A").End(xlToRight).Column

    st = ""
    em2 = ""

    If c > 2 Then
        'st = Format(Date, "DDDD") & "<br/>"
        For d = 3 To c

            If Cells(a, d) <> "" And CInt(Cells(30, d).Value) <= 7 Then
                st = st & Cells(30, d).Value & ". " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d).Value) & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d + 1).Value) & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d + 2).Value) & "<br/>"
                d = d + 2

            ElseIf Cells(a, d) <> "" And CInt(Cells(30, d).Value) > 7 Then
                If em2 = "" Then
                    em2 = Cells(30, d).Value & ". " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d).Value) & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d + 1).Value) & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d + 2).Value) & "<br/>"
                    d = d + 2
                Else
                    em2 = em2 & Cells(30, d).Value & ". " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d).Value) & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d + 1).Value) & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Cells(a, d + 2).Value) & "<br/>"
                    d = d + 2
                End If
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'If ActiveSheet.Name = "MON" Then
    'str = Cells(a, "B").Value
    'Else
    'str = Cells(a, "B").Value
    'End If

    If em2 = "" Then
        iMsg.HTMLBody = st & "Visa triet " & Cells(a, "AY").Value & "<br/>Total " & Cells(a, "B").Value & "<br/>"
        Set iMsg.Configuration = iConf
        iMsg.Send
    Else
        iMsg.HTMLBody = st
        Set iMsg.Configuration = iConf
        iMsg.Send
        iMsg.HTMLBody = em2 & "Visa " & Cells(a, "AY").Value & "<br/>Total " & Cells(a, "B").Value & "<br/>"
        Set iMsg.Configuration = iConf
        iMsg.Send
    End If

    Set iMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Function KeyVal(ParamArray ran() As Variant)
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim str As String
    a = 0

    Do While a < UBound(ran) + 1
        If ran(a) = 0 Or ran(a) = "" Then
            a = a + 1
        Else
            b = Sheets("Key").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            str = ran(a)

            If InStr(str, "/") > 0 Then
                Do While InStr(str, "/") > 0
                    d = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("/", str)
                    st = Mid(str, 1, d - 1)
                    str = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(Mid(str, d + 1, Len(str))))

                    For c = 1 To b
                        If LCase(st) = LCase(Sheets("Key").Cells(c, "A").Value) Then
                            KeyVal = KeyVal + Sheets("Key").Cells(c, "B").Value
                        End If
                    Next
                    If InStr(str, "/") <= 0 Then
                        For c = 1 To b
                            If str = Sheets("Key").Cells(c, "A").Value Then
                                KeyVal = KeyVal + Sheets("Key").Cells(c, "B").Value
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Loop
            Else
                For c = 1 To b
                    If ran(a) = Sheets("Key").Cells(c, "A").Value Then
                        KeyVal = KeyVal + Sheets("Key").Cells(c, "B").Value
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you? Which line of code is causing the crash? We're not here to do basic debugging of your code. Track down the section of code that is causing the problem, and then you'll be able to more clearly describe the problem and ask a **specific question** that we can try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use CInt(ran) for variable ran.

Use CDouble(keyval) for keyval.